# ayudá modelo entidad relacion pasarlo a tablas

Tags: mysql

soy nuevo en base de datos y nuestra profesora nos envío un diagrama de entidad relacion en myysql pero necesito pasarlas a tablas me podrían ayudar como paso ese modelo a tablas gracias

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: sí, podemos. Espero haberte ayudado :3

Answer (score 2):

En la barra de herramientas vas a encontrar la opción Database, al seleccionarla se expandiran más opciones, elegirás la opción **Forward Engineer**.

Después de eso se mostrarán varias ventanas informando lo que se va a realizar para crear la BD, únicamente tienes que dar click en siguiente hasta que finalice el proceso.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]